# Saving bytes from a binary file

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation

I have got a binary file and i need to load from `( x, y )` position `z` amount of bytes. For example I have got this sequence of bytes :

```
00000000  49 49 49 49 05 00 00 00  08 00 00 00 1a 00 00 00  
00000010  39 a6 82 f8 47 8b b8 10  78 97 f1 73 56 d9 6f 00 
00000020  58 99 d5 3b ac 7b 7b 40  b6 2e 9f 0a 69 b2 ac a0
```

---

```
( x , y ) = ( 1 , 1 ) | z = 3
```

- That means I have to load 3 bytes starting at `a6`
  For this purpose i use simple formula: ( x , y ) `position = 16 * y + x`, then jump there using seekg `binaryFile . seekg ( position )` and save bytes `binaryFile . read ( ( char * )&dest, z ))`

But sometimes It is not that simple and the position is not an integer but for example `position = 1,5` and `z = 2,5` bytes. How can i save that 1 byte ? ( coding is little endian )..

Comment: It's far from clear both what you want to achieve and what your problem is. For example, what is the meaning of an (x, y) position in a file?

Comment: The meaning of ( x ,y ) in a file is the position at which byte i start loading. Like i used in example. x = 1, y = 1 , position = 16 * 1 + 1 , position = 17 that means i will start reading from 18th byte in the exmaple it's `a6` saving z bytes

Comment: Are you positioning to *bits* within the file?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews no i am positioning to bytes.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is.  Use `seekg(position, ios::beg); read(&destination , 1);` to read 1 byte at *position* bytes from the *beg*inning of the file.

Comment: i can't jump at 2th byte and 4th bit  byte using seekg

Comment: @kvway I don't think anyone can help you until you explain what it means to specify a pair of numbers for position (I cannot tell if `position = 1,5` means the same as `( 1 , 5 )` ) and for z.  If you could explain what you would want from that, perhaps with an example of correct answers given the data you have already specified?

Comment: The position in a file must be converted to multiples of a byte sooner or later. So, if the conversion is not the problem, it would be clearer if you removed that conversion. If you actually have problems converting the position, it would be useful if you detailed that a bit more. Now, considering your claim that you can't read the 2nd or 4th byte using `seekg()`, that's not generally the case, I guess you must be doing something wrong there.